# Exporting a KML file from PHP

Tags: php, xml, laravel, character-encoding, kml

I'm facing a weird problem while trying to dynamically create an KML file (which is basically just XML) with PHP. I'm using the laravel framework and here's the view that generates the KML file.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="location.kml"');
?>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
  <Document>
    <name>Towers</name>

    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($points); $i++){ ?>
    <Placemark>
      <name>{{ $points[$i]['name'] }}</name>
      <!--HERE'S THE PROBLEM-->
      <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436-nodesc</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>{{ $points[$i]['coords'] }}</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($paths); $i++){ ?>
    <Placemark>
      <name>{{ $paths[$i]['name'] }}</name>
      <styleUrl>#line-000000-1-nodesc</styleUrl>
      <LineString>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>{{ $paths[$i]['coords'] }}</coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>
    <?php } ?>

    <Style id='icon-503-DB4436-nodesc-normal'>
      <IconStyle>
        <color>ff3644DB</color>
        <scale>1.1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
        </hotSpot>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0.0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id='icon-503-DB4436-nodesc-highlight'>
      <IconStyle>
        <color>ff3644DB</color>
        <scale>1.1</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
        </hotSpot>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>1.1</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id='icon-503-DB4436-nodesc'>
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436-nodesc-normal</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436-nodesc-highlight</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id='line-000000-1-nodesc-normal'>
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff000000</color>
        <width>1</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id='line-000000-1-nodesc-highlight'>
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff000000</color>
        <width>2.0</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id='line-000000-1-nodesc'>
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#line-000000-1-nodesc-normal</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#line-000000-1-nodesc-highlight</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

I exported a single layer from google maps and changed it as how I wanted. And this works just fine. But the only problem is that the first occurrence `<styleUrl>` tag in the code, when the file is downloaded, is just `Url>`.

There are also few other `<styleUrl>` tags but they work just fine. I tried remove all the PHP stuff and putting just static KML but still it outputs `Url>`. Any idea what could be wrong?

**Edit 1 :**

Variables being passed to the template are `$paths` and `$points`. Here they are in case it's any help.

```
// $points
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Nijraj Gelani"
    ["coords"]=>
    string(29) "-79.58523260,43.73280100,0.0 "
  }
}
// $paths
array(0) {
}
```

**Edit 2 :**

I tried to move the `<styleUrl>` tag up a little bit (although that is syntactically incorrect but just to get the idea) and it works fine as long as it's not child of `<kml>` tag in any way. i.e. putting it after `<?xml?>` tag works fine.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that you've triggered a bug in the blade interpreter that causes this. I see that you are only using one blade construct in your template. Try changing that to php and save your template as a php file instead of a blade.php file and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @delatbabel But it didn't worked. It still shows `Url>` in the file.

Comment: OK you have discovered a weird and wonderful new bug. I would like to see if I can reproduce it sometime. Your "solution" below really just introduces a new bug that masks the existing bug but if that's what you have to do then I guess you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not an ideal solution, I found a workaround by putting an extra `echo '<style';` before the `<styleUrl>` tag. I'd love to know why that happened though and I really doubt that anyone will face the same problem. :D